# Cannot pass from login popup page to password popup page in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a Selenium test for the account login. Each time when a 'continue' button is clicked it says:

> no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   `{"method":"xpath","selector":"//INPUT[@id='password']"}`

and remains on the email page, doesn't move to the password page. Though xpath of 'password' textbox is correct. My code is below.

**login class**

```
public class login {

  WebDriver driver;

public login(WebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

}


@FindBy(xpath="//LI[@data-cy='account']")
WebElement CreateorLoginButtonXpath;

@FindBy(xpath="//INPUT[@id='username']")
WebElement EmailTextBoxXpath ;

@FindBy(xpath="//BUTTON[@class='capText font16']")
WebElement ContinueButtonXpath;

@FindBy(xpath="//INPUT[@id='password']")
WebElement PasswordTextBoxXpath;

@FindBy(xpath="//BUTTON[@data-cy='login']")
WebElement LoginButtonXpath;



   public void clickCreateorLoginButtonXpath()
{
    CreateorLoginButtonXpath.click();
    System.out.println("login or create button is clicked");
}

public void TypeEmailTextBoxXpath(String email)
{
    EmailTextBoxXpath.sendKeys(email);
    System.out.println("email is typed");
}
public void clickContinueButtonXpath()
{
    ContinueButtonXpath.click();
    System.out.println("Continue Button is clicked");
}
public void TypePasswordTextBoxXpath(String password)
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(PasswordTextBoxXpath)).sendKeys(password);
    System.out.println("Password is given");
}
public void clickLoginButtonXpath()
{
    LoginButtonXpath.click();
    System.out.println("Login Button is clicked");
}



}
```

**main class**

```
public class RunloginTestCase {

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

login lg = new login(driver);

@BeforeTest
public void openBrowser() throws InterruptedException
{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
    System.out.println("Broweser opened");

}

@Test
public void loginTestPositive() throws InterruptedException
{
    lg.clickCreateorLoginButtonXpath();
    lg.TypeEmailTextBoxXpath("test1992@test.com");
    Thread.sleep(2000L);
    lg.clickContinueButtonXpath();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
    lg.TypePasswordTextBoxXpath("!Qwerqwer1");
    lg.clickLoginButtonXpath();
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    lg.clickSkipVerificationPopupPageButtonXpath();


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you provided a wrong formatted email address. Please try with a valid sample email like "test@test.test" ...

Comment: I have provided my personal email Id, that means valid format email. Actually it gives expectation in password text box popup page after click on continue button of email popup page

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RunloginTestCase {
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

@BeforeTest
public void openBrowser() throws InterruptedException

{
driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
System.out.println("Broweser opened");
Thread.sleep(3000L);

}

@Test
public void loginTestPositive() throws InterruptedException{

login lg = new login(driver);
lg.clickCreateorLoginButtonXpath();
lg.TypeEmailTextBoxXpath("email");
Thread.sleep(5000L);    
lg.clickContinueButtonXpath();
Thread.sleep(5000L);
lg.TypePasswordTextBoxXpath("password");
lg.clickLoginButtonXpath();    

}

}

Please try with this one
```